# Can I run Ubuntu in JavaScript (Linux emulator)?

Tags: browser, qemu

Is it possible to run Ubuntu in [JSLinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/)  ?

Here is today's [Slashdot post about JSLinux](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/11/05/17/0242244/Boot-Linux-In-Your-Browser).

Comment: That is... cool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. JSLinux only implements a cpu, interrupt controller, interrupt timer and a serial port. That is quite far from the [Ubuntu Hardware Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), such as a hard drive, graphics card etc.

If you had lots of time, you could probably create a suitable image based on Ubuntu, but it would be too far from the regular Ubuntu experience to be called an Ubuntu remix. See [the trademark policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy).